# DataTable ajax reload from different addresses

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

This is code I use for DataTable reload with ajax call:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "api/GetData" } );
```

This works fine, when I'm using DataTable on main page. When you access DataTable from Home/Index it will fail (404) to make proper ajax, because application receives **Home/Index/api/GetData** instead of **api/GetData** request. This can happen, because **main page and Home/Index points to same page** with table.

I didn't find anything on DataTable documentation (like to prevent paste ajax url to existing url and to main url). I could create Home/Index/api/GetData method but this is crazy, right? What can I do? Manually (on client side with js) change adress when hitting Home/Index to main page is another idea I just have.

Main page - I mean //someurl.com

Server is on MVC5 asp .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a slash at the beginning of the URL.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: '/api/GetData'
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)